# multi chains of pipes

Tags: exec, fork, pipe, dup2

I am **desperate**, I am searching for a month for reference/source code for multi chains of pipes, meaning that I can run something:

```
     cat /tmp/test.log  | wc -l --> stdout
                        | grep test1 --> stdout
                        | grep test2 | grep test3 |
                                                  | grep test4 --> stdout
                                                  | grep test5 --> stdout
```

Please don't send me to bash/tee/$... commands while tee works with files, and bash is too complicated to understand...

Note that the order does not care, the first chain that was finished will be handled as well.

Comment: Dear God, I hope I never have to maintain that....

Comment: What is the overall goal your are trying to achieve here? I think this may be the wrong way of attempting to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably break what you are doing up into multiple smaller tasks rather than trying to smash everything in one blow. Here is a BASH script that will do the same thing you want, but be much easier to comprehend.

Note: I did not test this, so there may be issues.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME='/tmp/test.log'
TMPNAME='mktemp -t' || exit

wc -l $FILENAME
grep 'test1' $FILENAME
awk '/test2/ && /test3/ {print}' $FILENAME > $TMPNAME
grep 'test4' $TMPNAME
grep 'test5' $TMPNAME

rm $TMPNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to develop something similar for a school project. The idea was to generalize the notion of pipes to achieve something like this :

```
 process1  --> process2
           --> process3 --> stdout
           --> process4 --> process5 --> stdout
                        --> process6 --> stdout
```

(loops are also possible)

In order to do this, my program did the following things:

- parse a file containing the pipe graph (processes and pipes)
- use fork() to create child processes
- for every child process, I close the writing end of the incoming pipes, I close the reading end of the outgoing pipes and I call execl(). The rest is handled by the child processes (beware of deadlocks!), depending on what you are trying to achieve.

In my case, since the processes called were also developed by me, I could just pass the pipes file descriptors as arguments to the child processes (--pipe-in .... --pipe-out ....), but since you are using existing programs based on stdin/stdout, you could use dup2() to "copy" the standard I/O pipes.

I do not know if this is how you plan on doing this, but it is doable that way.